# Is https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx no longer working?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-api, google-chrome-devtools

I have been using the below link format for the past few years to download crx files from the chrome store.

```
https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&prodversion=[PRODVERSION]&x=id%3D[EXTENSIONID]%26uc
```

Since last week this method no longer appears to be working for me, has anyone else encountered this and found a way around it? has this method become deprecated?

Comment: [Question](/q/7184793 "How to download a CRX file from the Chrome web store for a given ID?") this refers to

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67453990/1049870

The `x` parameter has changed a lot.